# Why do we use exponent in characteristic function?

Tags: normal-distribution, characteristic-function, probability-generating-fn

A student who is attending probability 101, learned about normal distribution and generating functions recently.

We are given a "generating function" as follows: $$G(t)=\langle e^{itx}\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{itx}p(x)dx$$

And we are asked to explain the following:

1. why is there an exponent
2. why do we use the imaginary unit

As I am really new to probability, few stuff that I knew is the function is a characteristic function, and it somehow related to Fourier transform (which I haven't learned yet). Could someone show me what to search for, or try to explain the above questions?

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3664401/321264.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read its wiki

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already been cross-posted and answered.